# Vote dissappeared -- I know I voted on this question and answer yesterday

Tags: support, voting

I typically go through the posts on the home page that were bumped by the Community user, review the question and answers, and vote on them.   Yesterday after the long weekend, about half the posts on the home page were there because they had been auto-bumped by Community.   I went through and voted on most of them.

Today I'm finding that the votes I made are no longer recorded there.  Is there a bug such that votes are not sticking?

Comment: Oh nuts! I just serial voted!!

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer.   Most of those questions were answered by a single user.   It appears that only my votes on that person's answers were lost.

The mechanism appears to be a StackExchange script that runs at 3 AM and reverts "serial votes".   That is when you vote on the items from a single person too many times.  See: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Sounds like a theory to me! Someone read several of my answers one day presumably because they like my answers and voted for quite a few of them. These were all reverted. Bummer! I understand the purpose of reverting serial votes, however, what is lost are honest votes. I cannot swear the votes for my answers were honest, but it appeared to be just like yours. How would the system know? I am sure something can be done, however, I am not sure I would want to write that code. It would get too tricky and could create more issues. Cheers!!